# How did Hankel determinants get the name Hankel-Hadamard?

Tags: linear-algebra, ho.history-overview

My question concerns the name for determinants of Hankel-matrices $H = (s_{i+j})_{i,j = 0}^n$.

In the classical textbook of Shohat and Tamarkin (1943) "The Problem of Moments", these determinants are defined without a name (on page viii).

In several math articles, I found the name Hankel determinant. In the field of physics (especially methods of moments), where I work, however, the common name seems to be "Hankel-Hadamard determinant"

Does anyone can give me a hint on how Hadamard is connected to this? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some background is given in the appendix of this 1988 [paper](http://pra.aps.org/pdf/PRA/v37/i12/p4557_1) by Handy and Bessis, who apparently introduced this terminology: *Hankel-Hadamard matrix, Hankel-Hadamard determinant, Hankel-Hadamard positivity, Hankel-Hadamard inequality*. It refers to a class of matrices of the Hankel form (constant diagonals) with a determinant that satisfies a generalized Hadamard inequality. The inequality is not quite the original [Hadamard inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_inequality) (it's a lower bound rather than an upper bound on the determinant), but the name stuck.

Comment: @Carlo Thank you very much indeed! I stumbled across the Handy and Bessis (1988) paper quite frequently when looking for an answer myself. As my institute does not subscribe to the APS "Physical Review A" Journal, however, I could not see the contents. Now I will try to get hold of a copy via interlibrary loan. Thanks again!!